# Template re-use initially shows old data

Tags: meteor

I might need to provide a lot more information for anybody to give me any meaningful feedback, but let me first attempt to describe the issue.

I have an app that lists items for sale. Each item has an individual unique page in my app, but the same template is used for rendering each of those pages. The first item page I load up is rendered perfectly. The same is true for the second page, but because the template has already been used to render an item before, I get a brief flash of the content (images and text) from the previous item.

Obviously, this could be an issue with me setting reactive variables after the template is rendered, but since I specifically destroy all reactive data associated with the template when I navigate away from the page, I am more inclined to believe that this is an issue with how a template is re-used by meteor. I would assume that the template is cleared of all previous data before it is re-inserted into the DOM, but that does not seem to be the case.

Anybody have any experience with this type of issue?

Comment: I've see exactly the same issue while developing [StockBase](http://stockbase.com), when switching from one news page to another.

Comment: Good to know I am not the only one. I guess it would be possible to manually destroy the template completely, but it just seems like that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: For what it's worth, this only seems to be an issue for me when running in production. On my local machine I am not having that issue. This would indeed indicate that it has something to do with how fast the template receives new data.

Comment: I also see this issue in both dev and production